# CodeSignal reverseParentheses Failing one case

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm, recursion, time-complexity

Write a function that reverses characters in (possibly nested) parentheses in the input string.

Input strings will always be well-formed with matching ()s.

- For `inputString = "(bar)"`, the output should be
  `reverseInParentheses(inputString) = "rab";`
- For `inputString = "foo(bar)baz"`, the output should be
  `reverseInParentheses(inputString) = "foorabbaz";`
- For `inputString = "foo(bar(baz))blim"`, the output should be
  `reverseInParentheses(inputString) = "foobazrabblim".`

**[input] string inputString**

A `string` consisting of lowercase English letters and the characters ( and ). It is guaranteed that all parentheses in `inputString` form a regular bracket sequence.

Guaranteed constraints:

```
0 ≤ inputString.length ≤ 50.
```

**[output] string**

Return `inputString`, with all the characters that were in parentheses reversed.

### My Solution

- Java Script

```
function reverseInParentheses(inputString) {
    let arr = inputString
    let start = arr.indexOf(')') < arr.lastIndexOf('(') ? arr.indexOf('(') : arr.lastIndexOf('(')
    let end = arr.indexOf(')')
    
    let temp = arr.substring(start + 1, end)
    if(start !== -1 && end !== -1){
        return reverseInParentheses(arr.substring(0, start) + 
        [...temp].reverse().join('') + 
        arr.substring(end + 1))
    }
    return arr
}
```

#### Problem

I am passing all cases except for final hidden case, no runtime or execution time limit error is being returned. So I am having trouble figuring out what scenario is causing the fail. I really want to use my own solution instead of copying the regex ones and in my mind this solution should work, perhaps a more experienced mind can show my folly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about ((see)(you))?

Comment: Without even looking at correctness, the algorithm is doing a bunch of linear searching: as many as 4 passes over the entire input per recursive call. At the very least, save your `indexOf` calls in a variable so you don't have to repeatedly walk the array over and over. There is a better way.

Comment: `String.prototype.reverse` will get also reverse the parenthesis. E.g. `)zab(rab`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your calculation of `start` and `end` really don't work.  And there's no simple fix to this problem.

The comment from Jonas Wilms suggests trying `'((see)(you))'`.  For this test case, you will get `start` and `end` like this:

```
          0    5
          ((see)(you))
          ^    ^
start ----'    '---- end
```

Note that the start and end are not an actual pair here.  There's another `'('` in between.

You can fix this up by doing a more sophisticated calculation of these values, by iterating through the characters, updating `start` every time you hit a `'('` and updating `end` when you hit a `')'`, then stopping.

That might look like this:

```js
function reverseInParentheses(inputString) {
    let arr = inputString
    let i = 0, start = 0, end = -1
    while (end < start && i < arr.length) {
        if (arr[i] == '(') {start = i}
        if (arr[i] == ')') {end = i}
        i++
    }
   
    let temp = arr.substring(start + 1, end)
    if(start !== -1 && end !== -1){
        return reverseInParentheses(arr.substring(0, start) + 
        [...temp].reverse().join('') + 
        arr.substring(end + 1))
    }
    return arr
}

console .log (reverseInParentheses('(bar)'))
console .log (reverseInParentheses('foo(bar)baz'))
console .log (reverseInParentheses('foo(bar(baz))blim'))
console .log (reverseInParentheses('((see)(you))'))
```

I don't particularly like this, combining the iteration to find the parentheses with recursion to keep reapplying the function until there are none left.  It feels awkward.

---

There are other solutions, as you noted.  One would be to use regular expressions.  Note that the language of balanced parentheses is not a regular language, and hence cannot be captured by any one regular expression, but you can repeatedly apply regular expression operations in an iteration or a recursion to get this to work.  Here is one version of that.

```js
const rev = ([...cs]) => cs.reverse().join('')

const reverseInParentheses = (s) =>
  /\(([^)]*)\)/ .test (s) 
    ? reverseInParentheses (s .replace(/(.*)\(([^)]*)\)(.*)/, (_, a, b, c) => a + rev(b) + c)) 
    : s

console .log (reverseInParentheses('(bar)'))
console .log (reverseInParentheses('foo(bar)baz'))
console .log (reverseInParentheses('foo(bar(baz))blim'))
console .log (reverseInParentheses('((see)(you))'))
```

Briefly, this finds innermost pairs of parentheses, replaces them with the reversal of their content, then recurs on the result, bottoming out when there are no more pairs found.

This solution was thrown together, and there are probably better regular expressions operations available.

---

But I actually prefer a different approach altogether, treating the characters of the string as events for a simple state machine, with a stack of nested parenthesized substrings.  Here is what I wrote:

```js
const reverseInParentheses = ([c, ...cs], res = ['']) =>
  c == undefined 
    ? res [0]
  : c == '('
    ? reverseInParentheses (cs, [...res, ''])
  : c == ')'
    ? reverseInParentheses (cs, [...res.slice(0, -2), res[res.length - 2] + [...res[res.length - 1]].reverse().join('')])
  : reverseInParentheses (cs, [...res.slice(0, -1), res[res.length - 1] + c])

console .log (reverseInParentheses('(bar)'))
console .log (reverseInParentheses('foo(bar)baz'))
console .log (reverseInParentheses('foo(bar(baz))blim'))
console .log (reverseInParentheses('((see)(you))'))
```

We can examine the behavior by adding this as the first line of the body expression:

```js
  console .log (`c: ${c ? `"${c}"` : '< >'}, cs: "${cs.join('')}", res: ["${res.join('", "')}"]`) ||
```

For `'((see)(you))'`, we would get something like this:

| curr (`c`) | remaining (`cs`) | stack (`res`) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "(" | "(see)(you))" | [""] |
| "(" | "see)(you))" | ["", ""] |
| "s" | "ee)(you))" | ["", "", ""] |
| "e" | "e)(you))" | ["", "", "s"] |
| "e" | ")(you))" | ["", "", "se"] |
| ")" | "(you))" | ["", "", "see"] |
| "(" | "you))" | ["", "ees"] |
| "y" | "ou))" | ["", "ees", ""] |
| "o" | "u))" | ["", "ees", "y"] |
| "u" | "))" | ["", "ees", "yo"] |
| ")" | ")" | ["", "ees", "you"] |
| ")" | "" | ["", "eesuoy"] |
| < > | < > | ["yousee"] |

I choose to process this state machine recursively, because I prefer working with immutable data, not reassigning variables, etc.  But this technique should work equally well with an iterative approach.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a thorough answer. It seems I still have miles to go before I sleep. And thanks to @JonasWilms for figuring out the failing scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this. It worked for me.

```js
function solution(s) {
    while (true) {
        let c = s.indexOf(")");
        
        if (c === -1) {
            break;
        }
        
        let o = s.substring(0, c).lastIndexOf("(");
        
        let start = s.substring(0, o);
        let middle = s.substring(o + 1, c).split("").reverse().join("");
        let end = s.substring(c + 1, s.length);
            
        s = start + middle + end;
    }
    
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read up on [answering questions well](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering).  While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

```
String reverseInParentheses(String inputString) {
    //recursion
    int start = -1;
    int end = -1 ;
    for(int i = 0; i < inputString.length(); i++){
        if(inputString.charAt(i) == '('){
            start = i;
        }
        if(inputString.charAt(i) == ')'){
            end = i;
            String reverse = new StringBuilder(inputString.substring(start+1, end)).reverse().toString();
           return reverseInParentheses(inputString.substring(0, start) + reverse+ inputString.substring(end+1));
        }
    }
    return inputString;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```js
function solution(inputString) {
    let s;
    let e = 0;
  while (e < inputString.length) {
      //if we saw a ')', we mark the index as e, then we go back the 
     //nearest '(', and mark the index as s
    if (inputString[e] === ')') {
      s = e;
      while (inputString[s] !== '(') {
        s--;
      }
      //get the string in the parenthesis 
      let beforeRevert = inputString.slice(s + 1, e);
      //revert it
      let reversed = beforeRevert.split('').reverse().join('');
      //put pieces together to get a new inputString
      inputString = inputString.slice(0, s) + reversed +
        inputString.slice(e + 1, inputString.length)
      //because we get rid of the '(' and ')', now we are at index e-1 of 
      //new inputString
      e--;
    } else {
      e++;
    }
  }
  return inputString;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
   function solution(inputString) {
    var parenCounter = 0;
    var leftPara = [];
    var lcount = 0;
    var rcount = 0;
    var rightPara = [];
    //count number of parenthesis.
    for(var i = 0; i < inputString.length; i++){
        if(inputString[i] == "("){
        leftPara[lcount] = i;
         parenCounter++;
         lcount++;
        }
        if(inputString[i] == ")"){
            rightPara[rcount] = i;
            rcount++;
        }
   }
  // console.log(leftPara);
  // console.log(rightPara);
   // for all the parenthesis
    while (parenCounter != 0){
        for(var i = 0; i < rightPara.length; i++){
            lcount = leftPara.length-1;
            rcount = i;
            while (rightPara[rcount] < leftPara[lcount]){
                lcount--; 
                rcount ++;            
            }
            var LastOpenIndex = leftPara[lcount];
            //console.log("LastOpenIndex: " + LastOpenIndex);
            var firstCloseIndex = rightPara[i];
            //console.log("firstCloseIndex: " + firstCloseIndex);
     var finalStr = reverseWord(inputString.substring(LastOpenIndex, firstCloseIndex+1));
//console.log("finalStr: " + finalStr); 
     inputString = inputString.replace(inputString.substring(LastOpenIndex, firstCloseIndex+1), finalStr); 
            // console.log(inputString);
            leftPara.splice(lcount, 1);
            //console.log(leftPara);
            parenCounter--;
        }
    }
    return removePara(inputString);
}


    function reverseWord(inputStr){
       // console.log("inside reverseWord: "+ inputStr);
        var newStr = "";
        for(var i = inputStr.length-1 ; i >= 0; i--){
            newStr += inputStr[i];
        }
       // console.log(newStr);
        return newStr;
    }
    
    function removePara(str){
        var newStr = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
            if(str[i] !="(" && str[i] != ")"){
                newStr += str[i];
            }
        }
        return newStr;
    }
```